# Executing a Liferay script from the specified node

Tags: scripting, liferay, cluster-computing, liferay-7.1

I want to execute a script from the Liferay script console, but I'm running a clustered setup, and I need the script to run from the specified node. Is there a way to do this?

The reason for this is to troubleshoot a network issue, which I can also do by ssh'ing into the node itself. Still, I'd like to know if this is possible because it would save us a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently the script is invoked from the node you're currently connected to. Connecting to a specific node depends on your setup, but seeing which node you're connected to you can put the following in your `portal-ext.properties` according to [this post](https://community.liferay.com/en_GB/blogs/-/blogs/where-am-i-how-to-know-which-cluster-node-you-re-on-):

```
web.server.display.node=true
```

Comment: In most of the systems I see, you can also grab the machine you're connected to from inspecting the session cookie, as it often has the name of the machine attached to it. This way it's not displayed on the page at all. Of course, you could also bypass the load balancer, but that's probably part of what you mention as "depends on your setup"